# Custom button detecting action outside image

Tags: iphone, button, action

I am developing an app and my requirement is to change the image of button on click.The images are basically the maps of the countries.So,the problem is I made a custom button but it is detecting the action outside the image as well(because image is curved and button is rounded rect by default).So is there any way by which I can customize the button exactly as per the image.

Thanks

Comment: I am not getting any answers,is it that difficult to implement?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean button with custom shape (custom tapable area) I wrote some method to check, that point in UIImage is transparent or not:

```
- (BOOL) pointInNontransparentArea:(CGPoint)point {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageView.image CGImage];
    NSData* data = (NSData*)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));

    unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];

    size_t width                    = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t bitsPerComponent         = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
    size_t bitsPerPixel             = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);

    size_t numberOfComponents = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;

    int pixelNumber = point.y * width + point.x;
    int byteNumber = pixelNumber * numberOfComponents + numberOfComponents - 1;

    unsigned char transparencyColor = pixels[byteNumber];

    [data release];

    if(transparencyColor != 0)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

If your button image has transparent background it will be easy - just check location of touch in button view and check ignore touches in transparent area.

Also you may check Ole Begemann class:
http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I am not able to understand the code and how it is useful.
But the logic you have written at last,I think is the correct way to go and even i was also trying the same thing with litle difference.
I was trying to to compare the co-ordinates(cgrect parameters) of the button(where it is tapped) and image,if the tap occurs in image area then i will change the color else not.
What do you think,is it a correct approach?

Comment: In this method I check that pixel with cordinates x, y (CGPoint) from image (imageView.image) has alpha component = 0. That means this point is 100% transparent. First I copy pixel data from image. Pixels array is one dimensional array in my code and I have to calculate which pixel i have to check (pixelNumber). Next, depends of image format, I calculate which byte i have to check in pixel data. This will works for RGBA format, because I always check last byte of one pixel (alpha value). If this byte = 0, it means this pixel is transparent.
And yes, yours approach is correct in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
And even the link you posted was very helpful,I got my work done.